# Text extraction and reformatting for output

Tags: powershell

I have a text file "e:\abc.txt" which contains data in this format

```
Heading Asia
 Name china
 val 200
 drt fun and play
END

Heading Europe
 Name paris
 val 234234
 drt tour
END

Heading america
 Name Ny
 val 234
 drt shop
END

[continued like this..]
```

I would like to create a new text file "xyz.txt" which extract selected headings and drt in the following format.

```
Heading    drt
asia       fun and play
Europe     tour
```

I have tried the following script:

```psh
$source e:\abc.txt 
$search "asia","europe"
$a = select-string $source -pattern $search -context (0,3)
```

output

```
Heading Asia
Name china
val 200
drt fun and play
Heading Europe
Name paris
val 234234
```

how to remove in between lines

```
Heading   - drt
asia      - fun and play
Europe    - tour
```

Comment: what did you tried yet? Im also not sure what you want to do

Comment: -1 Why are you double posting? You already asked this question an hour ago... These questions show no effort, attempts to understand or demonstrations of how to solve the problem you face. In addition, somebody already answered the previous one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell search string and get next line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050422/powershell-search-string-and-get-next-line)

Comment: Please understand that we want to help you but you need to answer our questions.

Comment: i tired so many scripts. but not working

Comment: @jisaak $source e:\abc.txt 

$search "asia","europe"

$a = select-string $source -pattern $search -context (0,3)

Comment: `so many scripts` you say... Please, post them. The only attempt I can see is the one from the person who answered your last question, which you have since deleted.

Comment: @arco444 that code is not working..

Answer (score 2):

Whipped this up to help since you have at least been trying something. I hope this does not go over your head but it uses regular expressions to help break up the file into its "sections" then converts each section into its own object. The advantage being that we can then filter using command PowerShell cmdlets like `Where-Object`. Its not as terse as I would like but as I said I just wanted to whip something up that would be *easier* to follow.

```psh
$path = "e:\abc.txt"
$headingstoMatch = "asia","europe"

(Get-Content $path | Out-String) -split "END" | Where-Object{$_ -match "\w"} | ForEach-Object{
    $hash = $_.Trim() -split "`r`n" -replace "^\s+" -replace "^(.*?)\s",'$1=' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $hash
} | Where-Object{$headingstoMatch -contains $_.Heading} | Select-Object Heading,drt
```

Using your above text file you would get something like this.

```
Heading drt         
------- ---         
Asia    fun and play
Europe  tour
```

Now you can export this to file easy using something like `Export-CSV`.

Comment: thanks @matt it works. actually i am new to powershell.  i tried my level best. it was my mistake for not giving proper  code